# "Linked Item Has Allowed Template" Field Validation XP 8.2

Tags: validation

We're trying to validate a Droptree field to only allow a certain template type be selected. We've found the `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/System/Linked Item Has Allowed Template`; the only field rule validator that is within `Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy`, all others are within `Sitecore.Kernel`:

`Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.Validators.LinkItemTemplateValidator,Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy`

We've created a new validator that references the `Type` above and set the `Parameters` to several variations of the following with no luck:

- `IncludeTemplatesForSelection={5A0F5DE2-8209-438E-A281-F8E8479B9565}`
- `IncludeTemplatesForSelection="{5A0F5DE2-8209-438E-A281-F8E8479B9565}"`
- `IncludeTemplatesForSelection="Event"`
- `IncludeTemplatesForSelection="/sitecore/templates/Event"`

Has anyone had success with this validator? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try IncludeTemplatesForSelection="Template Name"

Comment: @SivaKumar thanks for the reply, but still nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Linked Item Has Allowed Template” Field Validator is working as expected for Droptree field.
You need to add **DataSource=/sitecore/content/Home&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=Template Name** in Source field.

Note: IncludeTemplatesForSelection should be equal to Template Name without double quotes.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be an invalid entry in the Source field: `The item "Related Event" contains broken links in these fields: Source IncludeTemplatesForSelection=Event`

Comment: However, it does seem to work. Is there a way to include the `IncludeTemplatesForSelection ` parameter with a starting point in the content tree? For example:`/sitecore/content/Home/Calendar`

Comment: This looks like it might do the trick: `DataSource=/sitecore/content/Home/Calendar&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=Event`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you. I missed adding Datasource. I'll edit the comment.